# Several conditions for ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Is it ok to write this?

```
<button href="#" ng-class="{'disabled' : form.mail.$invalid && form.firstName.$invalid }"></button>
```

I thought it was right, but it doesn't work. I have a form, and I need to disable the Send button if these conditions aren't ok.

If I write only one condition, it works.

Comment: I think you mean an OR statement in here: `form.mail.$invalid || form.firstName.$invalid`

Comment: Yes it works with OR. But I thought that I need the && because every conditions has to be good. But it works with Or, so it's good for me! Thanks

Comment: Can you accept an answer if your issue is solved? :)

Comment: The good answer is in the previous comment (devqon comment). And I don't know how to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `(`, `)` on your condition:

```
ng-class="{'disabled': (form.mail.$invalid && form.firstName.$invalid)}"
```

**[JSFiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qzdq4uuh/)**

---

*As a side note, as far as I know your code should works well.*

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) attribute to the button with the proper expression. Not seeing your code, something along the lines of:

```
<button ng-disabled="form.mail.$invalid && form.firstName.$invalid ">... </button>
```